# Every scattered topological space is a Baire space

Tags: general-topology

Some definitions:

> A space $X$ is a called [scattered](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scattered_space) if every nonempty subset $A\subseteq X$ contains a point isolated in $A$.
>
> A space is called a [Baire space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_space) if every countable intersection of dense open sets is dense.  See Wikipedia for various equivalent formulations.

The following should be true:

> **Proposition:** Every scattered space is a Baire space.

Can anyone provide a proof?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will instead use the definition that every countable union of closed sets with empty interior has empty interior.

Assume $X$ is scattered, and suppose $\mathcal{A}$ is a countable collection of closed sets with empty interior. Let $U = \bigcup \mathcal{A}$. If $U$ has non-empty interior, then $\text{int}(U)$ contains a point isolated in itself. That is to say, there exists open set $O$ in $X$ such that $\text{int}(U) \cap O =$ {$x$}. Observe that $\text{int}(U)$ and $O$ are both open in $X$, giving us that $x$ is an isolated point in $X$. But $x \in A$ for some $A \in \mathcal{A}$, contradicting $\text{int}(A)$ is empty. Thus, $X$ is a Baire space.